# Use jetpack navigation to display back arrrow in the action bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I have a jetpack navigation graph setup with bottom navigation and an action bar. The bottom navigation has 3 tabs. 1 of these tabs has a detailed fragment that I would like to display the back-arrow on in the action bar.

In `MainActivity` `onCreate()`, I've added:

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

This displays the back button on every tab & fragment.

**How can I prevent display of the back button unless the user is navigated to a non-top level fragment?** Is there a method that detects when this particular navigation has occured? If so, I presume I can do something like `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`

Additionally, is there a way I can display a custom back arrow on the child pages? The default arrow does not fit the UI.

Happy to provide more detail if needed.

Comment: This is something [NavigationUI's top app bar support](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar) does for you. Is there a reason you aren't using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`setupWithNavController(BottomNavigationView,NavController)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView,%2520androidx.navigation.NavController)) and [`setupActionBarWithNavController(AppCompatActivity,NavController,AppBarConfiguration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupActionBarWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,%2520androidx.navigation.NavController,%2520androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration)) from `NavigationUI`. The first will bind the bottom navigation to the navigation controller, the second will set up the support action bar to regard the navigation.

With the [`AppBarConfiguration.getTopLevelDestinations()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration#getTopLevelDestinations()) you will be able to configure when to display the back arrow. The default is to only regard the root of the navigation graph as a top level destination, but you can also use another builder to define a set of top level destinations.